# Name of shortcut created by wix installer to support latin as well as Russian,Japanese and Korean strings

Tags: wix

I need to create an installer using wix which would create a shortcut entry. The name of this shortcut would vary with the language property specified by user while installing.
Now I have taken the approach of replicating the component tag for different languages.
Product Codepage is 1252.

```
<Component Id='XYZAppShortcutFr' Guid='XXXXXX'>
<Condition>LANGUAGE="fr"</Condition>
<Shortcut Id='ShortcutFr' Name='Démarrer $(var.ShortcutName)' Target='[INSTALLDIR]$(var.TargetEXE)' WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' >
</Shortcut>
</Component>

<Component Id='XYZAppShortcutFr' Guid='XXXXXX'>
<Condition>LANGUAGE="ru"</Condition>
<Shortcut Id='ShortcutFr' Name='начало$(var.ShortcutName)' Target='[INSTALLDIR]$(var.TargetEXE)' WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' >
</Shortcut>
</Component>
```

It fails with error:A string was provided with characters that are not available in the specified database code page. 
How do I make my installer generic to support latin languages along with korean/Japanese..?

Answer (score 0):

The right way how to do it should be by transforms... basically you need to make couple of installations.... for each language one, then make transform files... and then you will probably need to make an bootstraper (burn) and apply right transform to installer... 
More here: http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/transforms/morphing-installers